# Open graph tags for embeded youtube video

Tags: youtube, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I run my blog on blogger with a custom domain, and I have set up the template with Facebook open graph tags, they all work fine. The problem I'm now trying to figure out is occasionally I embed a youtube video in my posts, and I would like facebook followers to be able to view those videos without having to visit my site. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGraph tags for YouTube look something like this:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/{VIDEO_ID}?hd=1" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="360" />
```

Comment: Here's a reference to Facebook's OpenGraph documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags as well as a debug tool to help you verify your tags are configured properly:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Video is poorly documented. The og:video tag is mentioned in the list of Standard Object Properties, but the link to the associated documentation is broken. Searches for other documentation of video in OpenGraph leads to a bunch of newer information regarding "stories" and abstract concepts like "wants to watch". Standard Object Properties here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties

Comment: FWIW, Pinterest also recognizes videos with the above tagging scheme.